# copy_to and custom analyzer not working

Tags: elasticsearch

(I'm doing this with a fresh copy of Elasticsearch 1.5.2)

I've defined a custom analyzer and it's working:

```
curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/test -d '{
  "settings": {
      "index": {
        "analysis": {
          "tokenizer": {
            "UrlTokenizer": {
              "type":    "pattern",
              "pattern": "https?://([^/]+)",
              "group":   1
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "accesslogs": {
              "tokenizer": "UrlTokenizer"
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
}'; echo

curl '127.0.0.1:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=accesslogs&text=http://192.168.1.1/123?a=2#1111' | json_pp
```

Now I apply it to an index:

```
curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/test/accesslogs/_mapping -d '{
  "accesslogs" : {
    "properties" : {
      "referer" : { "type" : "string", "copy_to" : "referer_domain" },
      "referer_domain": {
         "type":     "string",
         "analyzer": "accesslogs"
      }
    }
  }
}'; echo
```

From the mapping I can see both of them are applied.

Now I try to insert some data,

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/test/accesslogs/ -d '{
    "referer": "http://192.168.1.1/aaa.php",
    "response": 100
}';echo
```

And the `copy_to` field, aka `referer_domain` was not generated and if I try to add a field with that name, the tokenizer is not applied either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything relevant in your ES logs that you can show us?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`copy_to` works but, you are assuming that since you don't see the field being generated, it doesn't exist.

When you return your document back (with `GET /test/accesslogs/1` for example), you don't see the field under `_source`. This contains the *original* document that has been indexed. And you didn't index any `referer_domain` field, just `referer` and `response`. And this is the reason why you don't see it.

But Elasticsearch **does create that field in the inverted index**. You can use it to query, compute or retrieve if you stored it.

Let me exemplify my statements:

- you can query that field and you will get results back based on it. If you really want to see what has been stored in the inverted index, you can do this:

```
GET /test/accesslogs/_search
{
  "fielddata_fields": ["referer","response","referer_domain"]
}
```

- you can, also, retrieve that field if you *stored* it:

```
  "referer_domain": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "accesslogs",
    "store" : true
  }
```

with this:

```
GET /test/accesslogs/_search
{
  "fields": ["referer","response","referer_domain"]
}
```

---

In conclusion, `copy_to` modifies the *indexed* document, not the **source** document. You can query your documents having that field and it will work because the query looks at the inverted index. If you want to *retrieve* that field you need to *store* it, as well. But you will not see that field in the `_source` field because `_source` is the initial document that has been indexed. And the initial document doesn't contain `referer_domain`.

Comment: Thanks Andrei! I successfully retrieved the referer_domain field, but it was the same as the referer field, the result from UrlTokenizer was not present, am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, to see the `analyzer` in action look at `fielddata_fields` output. That is what gets into the inverted index and what is the result of analysis.

Comment: Yep it works! Is it possible to put the result into _source field?

Comment: Not possible. There is another approach for "manipulating" fields - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html - but that also will not modify the initial `_source`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: I am creating a combined field using copy_to, it seems to be indexed, but it does not apply the analysis I specify in the combined field. Do you know if there is a way to do it? I added the mapping for the new combined field with index_analyzer setting, doesn't seem to be taking effect.